# Italics Fonts in Windows CMD

Tags: command-line, windows-10, fonts

I recently installed `Ubuntu Mono` from Google Fonts via the SkyFonts system. All four versions in the font family are installed (Regular, Bold, Italics, Bold Italics). I created the registry setting to allow it to be a font on within CMD. However, when I select it as the font on the CMD settings, it displays the italics version of the font, rather than the normal version.

[image: Windows CMD with Ubunutu Mono Italics]

So how do I get it to display the normal version of the font?

Answer (score 0):

Open `regedit.exe`, select `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` `Console`. Try changing the entry named `FontFamily`. It must be 0 but if the font wasn't standard could be 1, 2 or 3. Try these values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I went to try and test this solution, but it seems that Windows has fixed the issue by itself in the meantime.